# Chrome extension options not calling javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have an options page in my Chrome extension which calls a javascript file. I tried using javascript to save my options but it wasn't working, so I tested it with some very simple code:

**options.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="options.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**options.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert('loaded');
  console.log('loaded');
});
```

Neither the `alert` nor the `console.log` seems to be firing when I click `options` in the Chrome extensions page. This makes me think that the `options.html` file isn't loading the `js` file, but it could be that I'm wrong to expect `alert` and `console.log` to work like this with extension options.

Any ideas what's going wrong here?

Comment: `alert` and `console.log` should work.  Can you post your manifest?

Comment: Are you sure the files load properly? Right-click the opened page and click "Inspect Element" to open the dev tools and check for errors.

Comment: I needed to inspect the options modal window to get the `console.log`, stupid of me not to think of that. `alert` doesn't do anything, but that's ok. Thanks Xan for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @GluePear You should formulate that into an answer, so that this does not hang as unanswered. I'm perfectly fine if you do it - after all, the fact that `alert` does not work in this context is new and valuable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To see the results of any `console.log` you need to right-click on the options modal window and select "Inspect Element". Any console messages will appear here.

However `alert` commands appear to be suppressed, or at least I was unable to see any.

Comment: Thanks to Xan for the above.